# Средства на стороне сервера

Tags: c#

Какие средства нужны для создания сайта на стороне сервера (не считая html + css + javascript и тому подобные языки на стороне клиента)?

К примеру, есть связка php + MySQL + Apache + linux. Но я хотел бы использовать все прелести microsoft'a. Какая связка нужна в данном случае? (в обязательном случае, используя с#)? Я знаю, что надо использовать C# + MSSQL + ... (что дальше?).

Answer (score 4):

Вот посмотрите [ASP.NET](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET):

> ASP.NET — технология создания веб-приложений и веб-сервисов от компании Майкрософт. Она является составной частью платформы Microsoft .NET.

Answer (score 3):

Технология ASP.NET подразумевает следующие составляющие, про которые вы спрашиваете.

- Операционная система Windows.
- Веб-сервер Internet Information Services.
- Платформа .NET.
- База данных SQL Server (необязательно).

[Центр разработки на ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/asp.net/aa336522).